# angularjs controller defined in stateProvider not being passed into html page

Tags: angularjs

I'm hoping someone can explain why my controller is null and what I can do to get access to my controller in my html.  According to my $stateProvider, when I navigate to localhost:3000/display I should have access to my `DisplayController`.  However this doesn't seem to be the case.  I know the url is rendering the template (the table headers display) but there's no data.

I've tried putting a {{DisplayController == null}} at the top of the display-functionality.ng.html page, but it returns null.

I have the following $stateProvider

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
      .state('display', {
        url: '/display',
        templateUrl: 'display-functionality.ng.html',
        controller: 'DisplayController'
      })
      .state('display-non', {
        url: '/display/non',
        templateUrl: 'display-non-functionality.ng.html',
        controller: 'DisplayController'
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dispatches");
}]);
```

and my `display-functionality.ng.html`

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="information" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Time</td>
                <td>Address</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="display{{$index}}" ng-repeat-start="function in DisplayController.functions | orderBy: '-time'">
                <td>{{function.time | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</td>
                <td>{{function.address}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this seems suspect to me: `function in DisplayController.functions`.  If you are using the `controller-as` syntax, then you need to declare the state w. a key:value `controllerAs:'DisplayController'`.  I'd also suggest that you not use `DisplayController` as the instance name for the controller-as syntax.  If you're NOT using controller-as, then you need to remove DisplayController from your repeater

Comment: see @kachhalimbu's answer below

Comment: @jusopi so I took out the `DisplayController` and just had `function in functions` and that didn't work.

Comment: what does the code for the DisplayController look like?  Maybe there is more than one problem existing?

Comment: no,but I changed it to an inline as and it works: `controller: 'DisplayController as currentDisplay'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `controllerAs` syntax

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$stateProvider
  .state('display', {
    url: '/display',
    templateUrl: 'display-functionality.ng.html',
    controller: 'DisplayController',
    controllerAs: 'displayCtrl'
  })
  .state('display-non', {
    url: '/display/non',
    templateUrl: 'display-non-functionality.ng.html',
    controller: 'DisplayController',
    controllerAs: 'displayCtrl'
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dispatches");
```

}]);

and then in your view template files use the `controllerAs` alias you defined

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="information" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>Address</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="display{{$index}}" ng-repeat-start="function in displayCtrl.functions | orderBy: '-time'">
            <td>{{function.time | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</td>
            <td>{{function.address}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also remember to do this in your controller

```
var displayCtrl = this;
```

and all scope properties should be declared on this controllerAs alias variable in your controller

```
displayCtrl.functions = {};
```

Update: For route debugging I use this

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            console.log(fromState.name + ' to ' + toState.name);
        });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        alert(error);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: @MattWestlake do you see any error in the js console?

Comment: no,but I changed it to an inline `as` and it works:

`controller: 'DisplayController as currentDisplay'`

Comment: your `functions` should also be declared on displayCtrl for eg. `displayCtrl.functions = //whatever ` See this article http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/